# Change button color when clicked

Tags: java, background

OK, when I use setBackground on a button, the button no longer shows any feedback when its clicked. How can I fix this. I just want the button to get darker or some type of feedback so the user knows it was clicked.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this drawable and bind it to button background

```
<selector 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/YOURIMAGE" />
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
 <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/YOURIMAGE" />
 </selector>
```

Apply it to button

```
android:background="@drawable/button"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a selector inside the XML and have it linked to state_pressed = "true". Inside of the item, you can specify the shape of the object. I've linked to the Android developer site so you can see other options available as well.

```
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#73E5E4D7" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#E6E5E4D7" />
            </shape>
        </item>
```

[Android Developer State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: It's not set background. I ment to say that it's the tab under button that says background. When I leave it on default, there's an animation that darkens the button when it's clicked. However when you put in a hex value, the animation is gone.

Comment: Sorry, confused at what you're asking (maybe a screenshot would help). Can you give us some code/clarification/screenshot to what you're wanting?

Comment: When you specify what color value you want to use, there is no animation so when someone clicks the button there should be an animation in the button that darkens so the user knows of was clicked

Comment: Yes, so you would use the code that I've listed above. For instance, if you saved the code above as 'button_colors.xml' inside your drawable folder, you would make the button's <android:background = "@drawable/button_colors">

If you want it to STAY dark, you would use state_selected = "true" instead of state_pressed = "true"

Answer (score 0):

hope this works well. first assign your button into a button type reference in your activity class. 
ex: `newBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);`

after that set an listener to that button.

```
  yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            yourButton.setBackgroundColor(int colorCode);
        }
    });
```